# How to get the filename from the filepath in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

How to get the filename from the given file path string?

For example if I have a filepath string as

```
file:///Users/DeveloperTeam/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F33222DF-D8F0-448B-A127-C5B03C64D0DC/data/Containers/Data/Application/5D0A6264-6007-4E69-A63B-D77868EA1807/tmp/trim.D152E6EA-D19D-4E3F-8110-6EACB2833CE3.MOV
```

and I would like to get the return result as

```
trim.D152E6EA-D19D-4E3F-8110-6EACB2833CE3.MOV
```

Answer (score 209, accepted):

**Objective C**

```
NSString* theFileName = [string lastPathComponent]
```

**Swift**

```
let theFileName = (string as NSString).lastPathComponent
```

Comment: maybe you should highlight in Swift that this works only for NSString, like:

var theFileName: NSString = string.lastPathComponent
// or
var theFileName: String = (string as NSString).lastPathComponent

Comment: in Swift, local filenames are _highly suggested_ to be managed as `URL`s, not as `String`s or `NSString`s

Comment: Note that this requires `Foundation` to be imported. Not a big deal for iOS/Mac apps, but a big deal for Linux/Windows ones.

Answer (score 41):

SWIFT 3.x or SWIFT 4:
Shortest and cleanest way of doing this is below. In this example `url` variable is type of `URL` in this way we can have a human readable `String` result of the full file name with extension like `My file name.txt` and Not like `My%20file%20name.txt`

```
// Result like: My file name.txt
let fileName = url.lastPathComponent
```

Comment: this always returns asset.JPG for images.

Comment: See the Swift 2 answer which includes Swift 3 and is more coherent.

Comment: mine too - @HarshNigam

Answer (score 36):

If you want to get the current file name such as for logging purposes, I use this.

Swift 4

```
URL(fileURLWithPath: #file).lastPathComponent
```

Comment: Good to know: use `init(fileURLWithPath path: __shared String, isDirectory: Bool)` to avoid an extra file system access. From the docs: *This function avoids an extra file system access to check if the file URL is a directory. You should use it if you know the answer already.*

Answer (score 25):

**Swift 2:**

```
var file_name = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path_to_file).lastPathComponent!
```

Comment: This is the method the compiler says to use if you call `lastPathComponent` on a swift `String` (as opposed to casting to `NSString`).

Comment: Good to know: use `init(fileURLWithPath path: __shared String, isDirectory: Bool)` to avoid an extra file system access. From the docs: *This function avoids an extra file system access to check if the file URL is a directory. You should use it if you know the answer already.*

Answer (score 22):

```
let theURL = URL(string: "yourURL/somePDF.pdf")  //use your URL
let fileNameWithExt = theURL?.lastPathComponent //somePDF.pdf
let fileNameLessExt = theURL?.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent //somePDF
```

In order for this to work your url must be of type URL not a string so don't convert it to a string before hand.

You can copy and paste this code directly into playground to see how it works.

Answer (score 16):

Try this

```
let filename: String = "your file name"
let pathExtention = filename.pathExtension
let pathPrefix = filename.stringByDeletingPathExtension
```

**Updated :**

```
extension String {
    var fileURL: URL {
        return URL(fileURLWithPath: self)
    }
    var pathExtension: String {
        return fileURL.pathExtension
    }
    var lastPathComponent: String {
        return fileURL.lastPathComponent
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 11):

Below code is working for me in Swift 4.X

```
 let filename = (self.pdfURL as NSString).lastPathComponent  // pdfURL is your file url
 let fileExtention = (filename as NSString).pathExtension  // get your file extension
 let pathPrefix = (filename as NSString).deletingPathExtension   // File name without extension
 self.lblFileName.text = pathPrefix  // Print name on Label
```

Answer (score 6):

You can pass the url in fileUrl, like I did below:-

```
let fileUrl: String = "https://www.himgs.com/imagenes/hello/social/hello-fb-logo.png" // Pass the URL 

let lastPathComponent = URL.init(string: fileUrl)?.lastPathComponent ?? "" // With this you will get last path component

let fileNameWithExtension = lastPathComponent
```

//This last path component will provide you file Name with extension.

Comment: This is a little-appreciated code-only answer. Please add some explanation. That will improve your chances for upvotes and also helps fighting the misconception that you can get programming work done here free of charge.

Answer (score 6):

I've done some performance tests (iOS 14, real device, release configuration):

```
(#file as NSString).lastPathComponent // The fastest option.

URL(string: #file)!.lastPathComponent // 2.5 times slower than NSString.

#file.components(separatedBy: "/").last! // 7 times slower than NSString.
```

Bonus:

```
URL(fileURLWithPath: #file, isDirectory: false).lastPathComponent // About the same as URL(string:).

URL(fileURLWithPath: #file).lastPathComponent // 2.5 times slower than with explicit isDirectory.
```

Comment: While `(#file as NSString)` is the fastest, you'll get escaped stuff like `%20` in the result, which is resolved in the `URL(string: #file)` case.

Answer (score 4):

Swift 5. This one works faster than both `URL` and `NSString` options:

```
path.components(separatedBy: "/").last
```

Answer (score 1):

Creates unique "file name" form url including two previous folders

```
func createFileNameFromURL (colorUrl: URL) -> String {

var arrayFolders = colorUrl.pathComponents

// -3 because last element from url is "file name" and 2 previous are folders on server
let indx = arrayFolders.count - 3
var fileName = ""

switch indx{
case 0...:
    fileName = arrayFolders[indx] + arrayFolders[indx+1] + arrayFolders[indx+2]
case -1:
    fileName = arrayFolders[indx+1] + arrayFolders[indx+2]
case -2:
    fileName = arrayFolders[indx+2]
default:
    break
 }
 return fileName
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve filename without its extension from a URL in Swift >= 4.2:

```
let urlWithoutFileExtension: URL =  originalFileUrl.deletingPathExtension()
let fileNameWithoutExtension: String = urlWithoutFileExtension.lastPathComponent
```